# Are there any Asian superheroes in the Marvel comics who have ever had their own solo series, as of 2016?

Tags: marvel

I was talking with a Chinese friend about the *Doctor Strange* movie and he brought up that he was disappointed that the Ancient One wasn't Asian because there aren't any Asian superheroes in the Marvel Cinematic Universe. Upon further reflection, he couldn't think of a single Asian suphero in comics, certainly not one who had ever had their own solo series.

Are there any? The criteria is that they should be:

- Definitely superheroes (and not villains), or anti-heroes at best
- Are the protagonists (so Wong wouldn't count because he's a side character)
- Have had their own solo series released in 2016 or earlier

Comment: Why did you ask this question is you already knew the answer and instantly posted it?

Comment: @JackBNimble It's a self-answered question, [which are encouraged for this site](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). It seems better to write it as a question instead of "I know the answer, see below". I also thought it might be nice to show the process that led up to me doing the research.

Comment: http://comicvine.gamespot.com/profile/captain_solaris/lists/asian-superheroes-of-dc-marvel/17901/

Comment: http://comicvine.gamespot.com/profile/inhuman/lists/marvels-asian-characters/19816/

Comment: @Valorum Yup, I looked at that list. Not all of them are Marvel and of those that are Marvel, not all have their own solo series (most are X-Men).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Asian_superheroes

Comment: It is not wrong for someone to self-answer, but I wouldn't say we encourage someone to immediately post a self-answer in a 'look what I found out that I want to share.' Otherwise we could post thousands of such "questions."

Comment: @JackBNimble Why should we not want to immediately post a self-answer if there is a checkbox when you ask a question to add your own answer? I also thought that this was a question that others would have (I listened to a podcast lately where the same thing came up).

Comment: i assume that checkbox is due to stack overflow.

Comment: @Himarm They could have easily disabled the self-answer checkbox on this site if they were so inclined. [Scifi SE's help page explicitly says to use it](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @KutuluMike So if I add "As of 2016", then it's okay?

Comment: actually, sure; with _Doctor Strange_ and _Iron Fist_ coming out close to each other, 2016 is actually a relevant time period to ask this question, so I think that would be fine.

Comment: @KutuluMike Done! Thank you for giving me a practical suggestion for improving this question. Hopefully those who downvoted for that reason can undo it.

Comment: Are you specifically asking about 2016? Because your (self) answer seems to be about the entire span of time in comics.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots 2016 or earlier. Was there some wording that made that confusing? I'd like to change it if there is.

Comment: @Thunderforge: Ah. I read the earlier part, where you were asking if they had a solo series "as of 2016". I get now that you mean "have had" instead. :)

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Thanks, I changed it to say "have had" throughout.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of this writing, there have only been a handful of Asian superheroes who have had their own series. The first was in 1973 and then there was a big gap until the 21st century, with most being written in the last few yars.

### Amadeus Cho (Totally Awesome Hulk) — Korean-American

Winner of the "young genius" contest who used nanites to remove the Hulk from Bruce Banner and place it in his own body,

[image: Totally Awesome Hulk #1]

[Solo series since 2016](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Totally_Awesome_Hulk_Vol_1)

### Cindy Moon (Silk) — Asian (probably Korean)-American

Bit by the same radioactive spider that gave Peter Parker his super powers, making her have the same powers as Spider-Man.

[image: Silk #1]

[Solo series in 2015](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Silk_Vol_1)

### Daken (Dark Wolverine) — Half-Japanese

The son of Wolverine and his Japanese wife, who has much the same powers.

[image: Daken: Dark Wolverine #1]

[Solo series 2010-2012](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Daken:_Dark_Wolverine_Vol_1)

### Jubilee (X-Men member) — Chinese-American

A mutant with the ability to create energy plasmoids from her hands (and as of 2010, she's lost her mutant powers and is now a vampire. Comics are weird).

[image: Jubilee #1]

[Solo series 2004-2005](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Jubilee_Vol_1)

### Kamala Khan (Ms. Marvel) — Pakistani-American

A Muslim girl and an Inhuman with the ability to stretch her body.

[image: Ms. Marvel #1 Variant]

[Solo series since 2014](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Ms._Marvel_Vol_3)

### Shang-Shi (Master of Kung fu) — Chinese

A martial-artist and the Son of Fu Manchu.

[image: Master of Kung Fu #17]

[Solo series 1974-1983](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Master_of_Kung_Fu_Vol_1)

---

### Addendum

Of the [other Asian Marvel characters](http://comicvine.gamespot.com/profile/inhuman/lists/marvels-asian-characters/19816/), if they are not a supervillain, they tend to be a member of the X-Men.

The closest we have got to a headlining Asian superhero in the Marvel movies is [Yukio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukio_(comics)), who teams up with Logan in *[The Wolverine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wolverine_(film))* and has the power to forsee death. It's not part of the Marvel Cinematic Universe, but it is part of the X-Men universe.

[image: Yukio in The Wolverine]

Comment: "The first was in 2004" *ahem* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_of_Kung_Fu_(comics)

Comment: @PatrickWynne Oh wow, that's embarrassing that I missed that! None of the lists I saw mentioned that one, and I think when I read the title, I just assumed that it was one of the series that Marvel published that wasn't in superhero continuity (like the Romance Tales comics). I'll fix that now!

Comment: Are any of these actually Asians, or are they all Americans of Asian descent?

Comment: @DCShannon Aside from Shang-Shi (Chinese) and Daken (Half-Japanese), I think that they are all first generation Americans born in the US to parents who emigrated from their respective countries. I don't recall seeing Amadeus Cho's parents though, but there is an issue where he explicitly labels himself Korean-American. Yukio in the Wolverine movie is definitely Japanese-born though.